# PHP dynamic form input into a new html page form on submit

Tags: php, html, forms, dynamic

I am having some difficulty with inserting dynamic input fields into a new form html page. Essentially, I would like to get these dynamically created inputs into a new form field when the submit button is clicked on the previous page where the table dimensions are specified. Currently, when I view the page source, the input fields are outside of the html body. I would prefer not to have to use JavaScript just the keep things simple

//page where dimensions are specified e.g dimensions.html. clicking submit should bring you to a new page and display specified inputfields inside the html form.

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">          

    <label for="rows">Number of Rows (Min 1, Max 10)</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"  value="" name="rows" required>

    <label for="columns">Number of Columns (Min 3, Max 10)</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="3" max="10" value="" name="columns" required>

    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="post" /> 


</form>

     // loop for creating input fields from previous form input specifying table dimensions from seperate .php file

         $row = (isset($_POST['rows']) ? $_POST['rows'] : null);
         $col = (isset($_POST['columns']) ? $_POST['columns'] : null);
         $x = $row * $col;

         for ($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
             echo "$i<input type='text' name='content[]' required>",  "<br>";
         }
```

// new html page form page e.g. content.html

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="content[]">
```

// I would like to have the new fields input generated inside here

```
        <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="method" value="post"/>
</form>
```

Comment: In the new page, you have to run the for loop inside the form tag. I see that currently it is outside form tag. And also it should be inside the body tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

**page1.php**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">          

    <label for="rows">Number of Rows (Min 1, Max 10)</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="1" max="10"  value="" name="rows" required>

    <label for="columns">Number of Columns (Min 3, Max 10)</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" min="3" max="10" value="" name="columns" required>

    <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="post" /> 

</form>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
         $row = $_POST['rows'];
         $col = $_POST['columns'];
         $x = $row * $col;
    }

?>

<form action="script.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="content[]"> 
    <?php
         if(isset($x)){
             for ($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
                 echo "<input type='text' name='content[]' required><br>";
             }

         }

    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="post"/>
</form>
```